# how to avoid catching exception when accessing process property

Tags: c#, exception, process

I have an array of process
I need to print starttime of all processes. I can access to starttime of some of processes and when trying another ones it gives error "access denied" and throws exception

```
process[i].StartTime
```

How can I define without exception, that I don't have access to certain property of certain process. Thanks.

Sorry, It does not solve my problem. I don't need to access the property of process, I just need to know without exception if it can be accessed. I need to be able to write something like this:

```
if(process.canaccess("propertyname")) 
{ do something}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708/process-starttime-access-denied

Comment: Sorry, It does not solve my problem. I don't need to access the property of process, I just need to know without exception if it can be accessed.

Comment: can you pleas try enclosing the piece of code having startTime with try catch and then accordingly keep your logic ?

Comment: It is rather slow solution if I need to apply it to a number of processes.